# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes all the time

Tags: upgrade

Dell Inspiron 5551 8Gb RAM ddr3

I had previously (from manufacturer) installed Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked perfectly. A few days ago I installed the 16.04 version and I noticed that my new Ubuntu began to crash very often. I know that there are many similar topics but none of the solutions I found worked for me. My Dell freezes all the time and I hope someone will give me the right clues to solve this problem as fast as possible!

Comment: Would you mind posting the specs for your machine this will help other give you the help you may need to solve your issues

Comment: Boot from your live-USB or live-DVD and run memtest86+ for about 12 hours to check your RAM. Does it report any errors?

Answer (score 3):

Your processor is Intel Pentium N3540. This is affected by the [c-state bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051), where the processor attempts to go into unsupported sleep states. This happens with many Baytrail devices when using newer kernels. I have the same problem.

There is a simple workaround for this until it gets properly fixed upstream. You just need to pass a [kernel boot parameter](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) and the random freezing stops completely.

You do this by editing the configuration file for GRUB

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

This needs to be changed to include `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`

So after your edit it reads

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
```

If you have other boot parameters already besides `quiet` and `splash`, just leave them alone.

Now save the file and exit, and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

After reboot, the problem will be fixed.